# Do I need (will I ever need) LOCK IN SHARED MODE | FOR UPDATE within a transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, foreign-keys, innodb

I'm painfully struggling trying to understand how to write best my code and queries

straight to the question: do I need or will I ever need to write explicitly `LOCK IN SHARED MODE` or `FOR UPDATE` in a transaction (apart from `READ UNCOMMITTED` ones)?

if I have external keys, do I need to select rows explicitly to apply the lock to these rows, or the foreign keys definition is enough?

Comment: Transactions and locking are completely different features. I think you should explain your exact use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: absolutely yes.

The complete answer: it depends on the use case. Perhaps in the most of scenarios the default locks used by InnoDb is sufficient. These locks make sure that your data is consistent within a transaction. But here's a scenario that needs a lock using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`:

Consider you are making a web application in which your session data is stored in database. [Race condition is a concern](http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/) when it comes to session data. While this concern is satisfied when files are used to store session data, but if you move them to database it's your duty to make sure requests won't overwrite each other's session changes. In this scenario you need to read session data from MySQL using `FOR UPDATE` to make sure other requests will wait for this one to write back the session and commit the transaction before they could read it.

**[UPDATE]**

Here's a use case for shared mode:

Shared mode is useful when you want to make sure that some record remains unchanged to the end of your transaction. e.g. when you are trying to insert a child record with a foreign key to a parent when the parent record has been inserted in previous transactions. In this case you will first select the parent record locked in shared mode and then try to insert the child to make sure that when you are inserting the child, parent still exists. This way other sessions can still read the parent record but no one can change it. That's just off the top of my mind, but in the all use cases of shared mode lock this fact remains the same that you want a record to remain unchanged while it's still accessible for others to read.

**[UPDATE]**

Regarding the transaction isolation level of `SERIALIZABLE`, the [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_serializable) is pretty clear. If you set the transaction level this way, and also `SET autocommit = 0;`, then it's exactly like the `REPEATABLE READ` level plus writing all your select queries with `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` at the end (unless you mention `FOR UPDATE` explicitly). It means everything you'll touch (explicitly or implicitly) will be locked. Those that are selected without any mention of locks or those with `LOCK IN SHARED MODE` are locked in shared mode, and the rest in exclusive mode.

Comment: so basically innodb locks everything is selected in the transaction with LOCK IN SHARED MODE, but if you do it explictly with FOR UPDATE you'd get better performances and less deadlocks?

Comment: No. When you select a record in a transaction, nothig's locked. Others can change that record easily. To be precise, select locks records while they are scanned but once they are selected, their locks are lifted.

Comment: how is nothing locked? i tried in mysql shell using REPEATABLE READ, other transactions wait for the active transaction to finish. if it is not a lock, what it is then?

Comment: I'm not sure of your test scenario but I am of my claim. Here's how you should test it, in two concurrent sessions start the transaction and in the first one select a row, and in the second one update it. MySQL won't be locked at all and the update will go on. MySQL will only lock the second session if the first one had tried updating the record instead of selecting it.

Comment: that's what i did, and concurrent transaction gets locked :P try yourself, start transaction on client 1, select data (without adding any explicit lock), then start transaction on client 2 and select the same data (without adding any explicit lock) then go back to client 1 and UPDATE data you selected. now go to client 2 and try to update the same rows: it won't work until you commit in the client 1

Comment: ^ that using REPEATABLE READ

Comment: In your scenario it's not the `SELECT` statement that locks the record but the `UPDATE`. And that's what I said too: if you update a record in transaction 1, it's locked for transaction 2, even to select. But you can not lock a record by just selecting it unless it's `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. And that's the purpose of it. And be sure that I've tested my claim before posting it :)

Comment: ok, i'm starting to see how it works, however it is hard for me to understand when to use select for update/lock in shared mode. can you provide an use case? i'll reward you with a bounty tomorrow! thank you very much :)

Comment: thank you a lot for the update! again, i'm finally starting to understand how it works :D one more thing if you don't mind. how about SERIALIZABLE isolation level? would you recommend it over locking manually? feel free to improve your answer at any time, I think it says in a few words things that I couldn't find in the entire web :D